# SQL IDE runtime display format

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, dbeaver

This may be a dumb question, but my google searches aren't returning much of anything related.

At the bottom of multiple SQL IDEs I see the number of returned rows and two timestamps. What do the two timestamps represent? I have seen this in SQL Developer and DBeaver

```
200 row(s) fetched - 1m 57s (+33m 12s)
```

I am assuming the first is the time it takes to get the displayed rows while the second is the whole resultset.

Comment: There should be documentation for this, but I would expect the bigger value to be elapsed time and the shorter one to be "time spent in the database evaluating the query" -- processing time.

Comment: i only see the one timestamp

Comment: I only see intervals, no timestamps